# Cancel a user's search using lock and session ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, locking

My MVC application is handling searches via a standard search box on a webpage.  I'm trying to keep track of a user's searches - if they type a new search then I want to *cancel their previous search* and launch the new one.

I'm using a dictionary of sessionIDs and `Searcher` objects (my object that has a method `Search()` in it.

The issue I'm having is the flag to say `SearchInProgress` is never appearing as false and so the function that cancels a search is never called.  Possibly due to using a lock..? Here is the code in question:

```
 public SearchResultModel Search(string sessionId, string query, long time) {

    SearchResultModel results;

    lock (_lock) {
      if (_searches.ContainsKey(sessionId)) { // Check if this user (by sessionId) has already searched at all
        if (_searches[sessionId].SearchInProgress) { // Is there a search already in progress, and if so cancel it!
          _searches[sessionId].Cancel();

          while (_searches[sessionId].WaitingForCancel()) {
            // Waiting for cancel to complete - I'll replace this with a Timer later
          }
        }
      }
      else { // If user hasn't searched before then they'll need a searcher instance
        Searcher searcher = new Searcher();
        _searches[sessionId] = searcher;
      }
    }

    results = _searches[sessionId].Search(Db, query);
    results.time = time;
    return results;
}
```

Also, the class contains the following static members:

```
private static object _lock = new object();
private static Dictionary<string, Searcher> _searches;
```

`SearchInProgress` is a member variable of `Searcher` and is set to `false` on construction and then `true` when the `Search()` function is called... and then `false` again just before `Search()` returns the results.