# Cancel / end the rendering of a partial view using MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to speed up the return of search results in my MVC web app. If the user searches for one phrase and then searches for another straight afterwards I'd like to cancel the original search, **or realistically, cancel the rendering of results as this is what is taking time.**

**Edit:** the search box searches in real-time, hence if you type in something with lots of results, like "the", and then quickly change it to something more specific, then the original search holds up the latest one.

I originally thought that it was the database interaction that was the bottleneck (hence my question about cancelling db search requests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315731/cancel-a-users-search-using-lock-and-session-id)), but it's the rendering of all the results in a partial view that's the overhead:

My `SearchContoller` has this form:

```
public ActionResult Search(string query, string time) {

    // Go off and do search, returning results

    return PartialView("SearchResults", results);
}
```

If the `Search` controller method is used again while the first `PartialView` is rendering, can I cancel the original one somehow? For example in the view can I check a flag and cancel if that flag is set elsewhere?

View:

```
@model SearchResultModel

@if (Model.ResultType1.Count > 0) {
  <h2>Results 1</h2>
    <dl>
      <dt>Results:</dt>
        @foreach (var result in Model.Results1) {
           if (FlagInControllerToStopThis) break; // OR SOMETHING SIMILAR??
        <dd> <!--Each result is returned here--></dd>
      }
    </dl>
}
```

Comment: Rendering shouldn't be that slow unless you have a huge number of results and your rendering code does some expensive stuff. If it's a simple loop like in your example, it shouldn't be this slow. If you're using LINQ to SQL or a similar framework, looping over certain kinds of query objects can cause the original database query to fire over and over again if you don't materialize the results using `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: Yes the above has been simplified - the actual results have multiple types and for loops for each. And the `SearchResultModel` passed in contains all the data already, so db calls aren't a concern here (correct me if I'm wrong!).

Comment: Perhaps you're passing in an unmaterialized (lazy) query to the view, causing the database hit to occur in the rendering phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have the search box rendered as invisible, and then include some jQuery code in `documentReady()` to show the text box?  If there are no results, it will then be immediate, but if there are many, when the page is returned it can't be used.

Theoretically the user could use *another* screen to do another query, but I think that may be beyond the scope of the question.

**Edit given comment below**

If you're using MVC 4, you could make the search method *asynchronous*, see [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) article on how to do that.  One could then potentially cancel that using something like a `ManualResetEvent`, provided the code that was searching could see if it was set and stop itself.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain the search feature that well, but it uses realtime searching, so as you type it returns results.  It's pretty quick and works well usually, but if you create a nasty search term with loads of results and then edit it quickly to something simpler then the original search request takes ages and holds up the new one.

Comment: +1 for editing so quickly given my comment, and thanks for the suggestion - I'll go off and give it a try.